# Video frames fill only 1/4 of the view - GL

Tags: ios, swift, glkit

I have View - "cameraView" which is used to display view from camera by glView.
when I set `glView = GLKView(frame: self.cameraView.bounds, context: glContext!)`
like that it fills whole cameraView but a video frames displayed by `ciContext?.drawImage(image, inRect:self.cameraView.bounds, fromRect:image.extent)` fills only 1/4 of the view (tested on iPhone 5c), but on iPad2 everything is good.

```
glContext = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)
glView = GLKView(frame: self.cameraView.bounds, context: glContext!)
ciContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: glContext!)
self.cameraView.addSubview(glView!)
```

...

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
{
    if photoTaken == false
    {
        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!

        let image = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)

        if glContext != EAGLContext.currentContext()
        {
            EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(glContext)
        }

        glView?.bindDrawable()
        ciContext?.drawImage(image, inRect:self.cameraView.bounds, fromRect:image.extent)//?
        glView?.display()
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

ciContext.drawImage(...) draw image in pixels, so image "inRect:" width and height must be multiply by UIView.contentScaleFactor which is 1.0 on old iPhones, 2.0 and 3.0 on iPhones with higher resolution.